# How to quit a job I have been staying for a week?

Tags: resignation

I am currently a sports analyst.
I accepted this job because I love sports, and well when I took the entrance exam I passed it and I was surprised because I am not really good in math.

Now one week from my first day. The training is brutal for me because the math is advanced math. The newly hired people came from being engineers and mathematics courses from college. I came from business administration and thus I cannot keep up with them with the math.

I don't have a boss or a supervisor yet because we are still in training and different people from different departments train us per day.

So how do I quit my job respectfully?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have a private talk with the relevant tutor and describe what you're facing problems with and use this to talk about your options moving forward.

The fact that you were accepted for the role means that you are suited for the job at least in most aspects.

So, talk about your difficulties and see whether your tutor can find ways of helping you succeed rather than immediately admitting defeat over difficulties with only one aspect of the training.

Assume that difficulties might be presented to you as a way of assessing how you deal with difficult situations.  Acknowledging your weaknesses and how you seek to address them might be part of your ongoing training.  Describing your problems and asking for help is a lot better than simply walking away.

Comment: This is a great answer. Show that you're willing to rise to the challenge instead of immediately running away. Even if you eventually leave this job, taking all possible steps to help yourself succeed will make this a *success story* in future interviews instead of a *big black mark* because you ran at the first sign of difficulty.

Comment: To add to this, no matter what job you undertake, there will always be challenges which at first sight seem impossible. Same with all those other trainees you're with, it will just be a different obstacle for them. Don't drop the ball this quick. Just come to terms that things can be difficult, and struggling with things is extremely normal.

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer. Also, if at all possible, try to have a discussion about this with someone higher up and responsible for you. _Don't_ tell them you're thinking about quitting - only express your concerns about math.